# PROLOG - How to search using the value read from keyboard

Tags: prolog

I guys, I want to do the following using the following search prolog: Return all the people who have the same sex, but that sex should be read from the keyboard. I could do without reading the keyboard and the code looks like this:

```
person('1', 'Joane', 'Women').  
person('2', 'John', 'Man').  
person('3', 'Peter', 'Man').  
listaBySex(List):-  
findall(Name, pessoa(_, Name , 'Man'), List).
```

Now my difficulty is to do this research with the value being read from the keyboard, I can read the value from the keyboard most do not know how to relate this value to read findall to return the value at the moment the code looks like this:

```
person('1', 'Joane', 'Women').  
person('2', 'John', 'Man').  
person('3', 'Peter', 'Man'). 
listaBySex(List):- 
write('Sex: '), read(Sex),
findall(Name, pessoa(_, Name , Sex), List).
```

Comment: OT, but it should be `person('1', 'Joane', 'Woman').`

Comment: Just to clarify the message from George, you should accept Daniel's answer (click on the check...)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that your database has `person/3` and you're calling `pessoa/3`, your code works as-is, you just need to quote the sex when you enter it:

```
?- listaBySex(List).
Sex: 'Man'.
List = ['John', 'Peter'].

?- listaBySex(List).
Sex: 'Women'.
List = ['Joane'].
```

The problem is that `read/1` reads a Prolog term, so when you enter `Man` without quotes, Prolog reads it as a variable, so your code effectively becomes the same as this:

```
listaBySex(List) :-
  read(_), findall(Name, pessoa(_, Name, _), List).
```

which is why it returns the entire database. You probably will need to handle input a little more carefully to make it do what you want. After all, you probably don't want to have to enter a period at the end of the line either.